# what's the advantage of using displaylist?

Tags: opengl

I can not understand displaylist clearly. For example, if I want to draw a scene with complex light and may change the material which used by objects in the scene. The speed of setting material may low, so I can put the definition of material in displaylist. So what's the advantage of using displaylist?

Comment: http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_displaylist.html -- with display list the calls are cached in GPU memory and do not need to be transferred every time from CPU to GPU.

Comment: Note that display lists are not available in OpenGL ES, which is one your tags.

Comment: @msell but in android the hwui uses displaylist.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen in ur opinion, does matrixes also stored in GPU memory, but if you change the data of matrixes, it also need to be transferred from cpu to gpu?

Comment: @james: "*but in android the hwui uses displaylist*" Are you sure it's using actual OpenGL display lists, rather than a tool of it's own making that they happen to call a "display list"? Because ES 2.0 doesn't have display lists.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen I think the commands don't neccessarily have to be cached on the GPU (I think insufficient specification of how they should be implemented was one of the problems of display lists, leading to varying performance gains across implementations). But even if not cached on the GPU it is still an advantage if you don't have to make a whole bunch of driver calls istead of a single simple call to excute a prebuilt batch of commands. Lowering app-driver communication is already a win, even if not lowering CPU-GPU communication.

Comment: @NicolBolas I have fixed up the displaylist in android, the displaylist in android is a technique for hardware acceleration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Display Lists essentially are macro recorders / players. When compiling a display list, the OpenGL implementation records all the commands sent to it into once single object. Unfortunally display lists are a bit cumbersome to work with. For example a display list *will* store data passed to texture objects (they used to be used as texture store in OpenGL-1.0, ca. 1992, before the introduction of texture objects), but they won't store geometry data drawn through vertex arrays.

Any performance gains obtained through display lists are due to the possibility of batching up a lot of immediate mode calls, as a (GPU side) vertex array allows. With *Vertex Buffer Objects* available, this use of display lists became obsolete. This was about around 2000. The only remaining use of display lists was to encapsulate OpenGL state settings, which was usefull, as setting keeping book of the state for the fixed function pipeline was quite tedious. Ever since OpenGL got fully shader based much of the fixed function state became obsolete as well. Today what you've done by calling a gazillion of OpneGL state calls (or one glCallLists) is replaced by simply selecting the right shader program for the task at hand.

Ever since the display lists are completely obsolete and offer no viable performance gain.

It's also noteworthy, that OpenGL side matrix math operations (glLoadIdentity, glTranslate, glRotate, etc.) are not performed by the GPU. The matrix is prepared by the driver and then just uploaded to the GPU. Display lists just store the prepared matrix and upload it as well. But from a bandwidth and performance point of view, there's no difference in calling glUniform / glLoadMatrix yourself or having a display lists trigger that codepath. So Khronos did the reasonable thing and removed display lists from any modern OpenGL version and variant.

***TL;DR:** Display Lists used to be a usefull tool when Vertex Buffer Objects were not available to put geometry into fast memory and to compile larger sets of OpenGL state into an single name. On modern OpenGL display lists no longer offer advantages and would just increase driver size and complexity, so display lists have been removed from modern OpenGL variants.*

Comment: one thing, i am confused is that, when using displaylit, dose it need to calculate the matrix in client and then upload to server? thanks.

Comment: @james: Now it's getting interesting. Windows one could say, the GPU is the server. But Client, Server, GPU, those are 3 separate things on plattforms like X11/GLX. Display lists have been an integral part of X11 from the very beginning, and the OpenGL display lists just work through the same mechanism there: They are server side macro recorders, i.e. the commands from the client are compiled into macros stored on the server side. Then a single glDrawLists command will trigger the server to do play back the macro to the GPU.

Comment: @james: Of course most OpenGL implementations are so clever to bundle geometry batches into fast-memory, i.e. on the GPU. But technically it was perfectly valid for a display list to be executed from the server's CPU as single commands to the GPU.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. May be I haven't caught your point, on android platform, the app is like a client and the gpu is server? I want to know wheather the matrix multiply is done in gpu side or cpu side? thanks.

Comment: @james: In fixed function pipeline OpenGL (i.e. no shaders used) all matrix stack operations (glRotata, glTranslate, etc.) are performed on the CPU. Ever since T&L GPUs were introduced (ca. 1997), the vertex vector matrix multiplications happen on the GPU (that's the T&L part). Nowadays GPUs are fully programmable and it depends on *your* programming, where things happen. But: GPUs are great at doing the same operations with a lot of different input data. Transformation matrices usually are shared among all vertices, so building transformation matrices is still a job best done on the CPU.

Comment: @james: About the distinction client and server: In some sense the GPU may be seen as server. However most of the notation regarding clients and servers in OpenGL actually comes from X11, where both client and server are executed on a CPU; the server acts as an intermediary to the GPU. So if you're running on a Linux machine with X11, then you're dealing with exactly this triptych: A client (your program), the server (managing the display) and the GPU.

Comment: Thanks again, i thinks there is a long way for me, ^ ^